# Using multiple $routeparams in a url string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-resource

Per this post, I am trying to use two parameters in an URL string to link to an individual result in a REST call:

[Set URL to SEO Friendly Title with Dashes instead of ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260394/set-url-to-seo-friendly-title-with-dashes-instead-of-id/27529317#27529317)

My list of articles and links populate as expected, but once a link is clicked on to retrieve the details of an individual article, it doesn't resolve. I suspect it is how I am "getting" my routeparams. It works if I declare a single route param, but I need both the id and title of the article to ensure uniqueness.

Controllers.js

```
var pfcControllers = angular.module('pfcControllers', []);

pfcControllers.controller('pfcCtrl', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, pfcArticles) {
    $scope.articles = pfcArticles.query();
}]);

pfcControllers.controller('pfcCtrl2', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, $routeParams, pfcArticles) {
    $scope.article = pfcArticles.get({ articleID: $routeParams.articleID, articleTitle: $routeParams.articleTitle });
}]);
```

App.js

```
var pfcModule = angular.module('pfcModule', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'pfcServices', 'pfcControllers']);

pfcModule.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/home', { templateUrl: './views/home.html'}).
    when('/categories', { templateUrl: './views/categories.html', controller: 'pfcCtrl' }).
    when('/article/:articleTitle/:articleID', { templateUrl: './views/article.html', controller: 'pfcCtrl2' }).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
}]);
```

Services.js

```
var pfcServices = angular.module('pfcServices', ['ngResource'])

pfcServices.factory('pfcArticles', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles/:articleTitle/:articleID', { articleTitle: '@articletitle', articleID: '@id' });
}]);
```

Articles.html

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="article in articles">
            <td>{{article.id}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articletitle}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articlecategoryid}}</td>
            <td><a href="#article/{{article.articletitle}}/{{article.id}}">{{article.articletitle}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Article.html (This is the one that is not resolving/matching the routeparams. It works for a single routeparam but not two)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{article.id}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articletitle}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articlecategoryid}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articlesummary}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: First, could you set up a plunker/jsFiddle? Second, if you need parameters in the URL you could just use the $location.search service and get/set parameters with it. The only difference is it would be at the end of the URL and following a "?"

Comment: Put the ID before the title in the URL, then just extract the ID and treat the title as junk. You'll want to retrieve the title from the database instead.

Comment: @Blazemonger, that works. I have a friendly URL and a unique call via the ID

Comment: Exactly -- the title may be edited later, or it might get cut off halfway, or for social media may be removed entirely. In that case, you should add a [canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066) to each page so Google doesn't index every possible URL. (StackOverflow does this too!)